# Why does fixing 'initialization of variable 'error' was never used;' result in a new error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning from a tutorial that I had to convert to the newest version of Swift. It went mostly well except that I'm stuck with a warning: "Initialization of variable 'error' was never used; consider replacing its assignment to '_' or removing. Here's the code:

```
  class func loadMembersFromFile(path:String) -> [Member]
     {
      var members:[Member] = []

      var error:NSError? = nil
      if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:[]) ,
      json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])) as? NSDictionary,
      team = json["team"] as? [NSDictionary] {
      for memberDictionary in team {
      let member = Member(dictionary: memberDictionary)
      members.append(member)
      }
    }
   return members
   }
```

I understand that error so I'm following Xcode's advice and changing the offending line to:

```
_:NSError? = nil
```

That results in two new errors; 'Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' and 'Expected expression'

It's pretty obvious these are syntax errors so I hope this isn't a dumb question but which are the consecutive statements? Also, why would these errors only appear after I make a change Xcode is suggesting?

Comment: It means that the variable `error` was never used.  You can, in fact, delete that line.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Please, no more negative votes on the question. I promise you that I searched far and wide here and other places for help with this before I posted anything. I even found a thread with the very same piece of code but addressing a different question. Lesson learned, okay? Next time I'll explicitly state what I've done on my own before posting.

Comment: Anyone who down voted, this isn't a bad question. This actually counts as a bug in Xcode since it replaced the constant wrong. The OP was just asking why Xcode told him to do something that was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out myself, it seems that Xcode's "advice" also deleted the `let` keyword instead of leaving it with the new variable name, `_`.

Since there is no longer any variable assignment, a syntax error comes up. The two consecutive statements Xcode is seeing are `_` and `:NSError = nil`. So, it thinks you've made a mistake and forgotten to put a semicolon between two statements on the same line (`Consecutive statements on the same line must be replace by a ';'`). It advises you to put a semicolon there, and when you do, it realises that neither `_` nor `:NSError = nil` are valid expressions, and tells you so with `Expected Expression`.

But none of that matters, because Error Handling has moved from NSErrors to `try/catch` and that NSError isn't used anymore. You'll be fine just deleting it. PS, you should put any code with `try` statements in a `do` block and then handle any errors in a `catch` block

Answer (score -1):

Just delete that whole line.  I assume that the error you're getting after making the change is because you also deleted the `var` keyword?  Either way, just delete the line and you'll be in good shape.